# Is there a way to read the content of doc or docx document in UWP?

Tags: .net, uwp, windows-10-universal, mobile-development, .net-core

I am new to Universal Windows Platform, just created a UWP project to get familiar with the stack and I'm looking to read the contents of .doc / .docx document.

I haven't found any namespace associated with Office, I've found a few libraries on NuGet, but they are incompatible with UWP.

Could you please suggest a way to go about reading a word document?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Document support (rtf, doc, docx) for UWP/Windows 10 Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572614/document-support-rtf-doc-docx-for-uwp-windows-10-mobile)

Comment: For MS Word document, especially the version after 2007, it uses Open-XML-SDK and currently it doesn't support UWP platform. You can try to find a free service for this, or using the method in the answer provided by @Bart, but all these methods needs internet support.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT thank you very much for the info!